# How to replace comma with apostrophe/single quote?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

How do I replace comma with apostrophe/single quote in pgsql select query?
My current query is:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(districtname), ', ') as dnames
FROM districts
where id in ('' || Replace((select districtIds from tblmtr where id = 1), ',' , ''',''') || '');
```

It is returning null.
Id's in table `tblmtr` are like this `2`,`3`,`4`

When I change it to only `2` or `3` or `4` it returns the correct result.
Result should be like this: `district1name,district2name,district3name`

Comment: It seems that you try to use `in` in wrong way. Try `... where id = any(string_to_array((select districtIds from tblmtr where id = 1), ',')::int[])` instead.

Comment: yes i have already done it. it helped me actually :) So Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Your Postgres version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are not ideal here:

- Upgrade to a modern **version** of Postgres. [Version 8.4 reached EOL in 2014.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)
- Have a look at [database **normalization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and reconsider your relational design. It's typically a *very* bad idea to store multiple ID values in a comma-separated string.
- `IN` would expect a [subquery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) or a [list of values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20283). You seem to try and provide a string containing the values, which does not work. Consider a `JOIN` instead of your awkward `IN` construct.

While stuck with your unfortunate design, convert the comma-separated string to an array on the fly and use the [`ANY` construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN16589).
You neglected to provide your table definitions, so making a few assumptions.

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(d.districtname), ', ') AS dnames
FROM   tblmtr    t 
JOIN   districts d ON d.id = ANY (string_to_array(t.districtIds, ','))
WHERE  t.id = 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT d.districtname
   FROM   tblmtr    t 
   JOIN   districts d ON d.id = ANY (string_to_array(t.districtIds, ','))
   WHERE  t.id = 1
   ) AS dnames;
```